# Mensaje Future Warning utilizando numpy

Tags: python, numpy

He ejecutado un script con las siguientes lineas de código.

```
import pywt
import numpy as np 
...
[coeficientes, frecuencias] = pywt.cwt(signal, escalas, nombre_wavelet, dt)
periodos = 1.0 / frecuencias
minimo = np.ceil(np.log2(periodos.min(axis=0)))
```

El script retorna los resultados esperados, pero en la terminal aparece el siguiente mensaje.

```
/home/oscar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py:6554: MaskedArrayFutureWarning: In the future the default for ma.minimum.reduce will be axis=0, not the current None, to match np.minimum.reduce. Explicitly pass 0 or None to silence this warning.
  return self.reduce(a)
```

¿Cómo podría evitar ese mensaje?

Comment: Aclaras que version de numpy esas usando? porque segun google, alcanza con que actualices a la ultima version...

Comment: Versión python 3.5.2

Comment: esa es la version de numpy?

Comment: usa matplotlib? parece que el error viene por esa libreria...

Comment: version numpy 1.18.5

Comment: Si, utiliza matplotlib.

Comment: La versión original era
    yticks = 2**np.arange(np.ceil(np.log2(period.min())), np.ceil(np.log2(period.max())))
y la modifiqué así
    minimo = np.ceil(np.log2(periodos.min(axis=0)))
    maximo = np.ceil(np.log2(periodos.max(axis=0)))
    yticks = 2**np.arange(minimo, maximo)
pero el warning continúa apareciendo.

Comment: Disculpa, soy nuevo, no sé cómo introducir newline

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar filterwarnings:

```
from warnings import filterwarnings
filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Answer (score 1):

Estos warnings suelen venir porque tienes desactualizadas algunas de las siguientes bibliotecas, **actualizalas a su última versión.**

- Numpy V1.19
- Pandas V1.1
- Matplotlib V3.2

Paara actualizar dichas bibliotecas puedes usar el siguiente comando:

### si utilizas pip

`pip install matplotlib --upgrade`

### Si utilizas Anaconda

`conda update numpy`